# ng2-pdf-viewer Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: angular, pdf

I am using the ng2-pdf-viewer library for Angular and I am trying to display a PDF from a basic url.
the problem is I get the following error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://www.bbv.ch/images/bbv/pdf/Publikationen/BBV16Poster_Angular2.pdf.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54800' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Here is my code :

.ts :

```
{ Name: "Angular2 tuto", Description: "An amazing Angular2 pdf !", Url: {url: "https://www.bbv.ch/images/bbv/pdf/Publikationen/BBV16Poster_Angular2.pdf", withCredentials: true} }
```

.html :

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="document.Url" [page]="1" [original-size]="false" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```

I tried with and without "withCredentials" property - nothing changed..

How can I show any pdf from a link in angular2 ? (worked in a basic iframe though...)

Comment: I have the same problem, any advance?

Answer (score -4):

Import these :-

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

define variable :-

```
Url : SafeUrl;
```

Use it in constructor like this-

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

Specifiy URL like this-

```
this.Url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("https://www.bbv.ch/images/bbv/pdf/Publikationen/BBV16Poster_Angular2.pdf");
```

Comment: Please post answer after u tested it. This is not working