# ng2-pdf-viewer "need either .data, .range or .url" problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a problem with ng2-pdf-viewer directive. At first I had a 
Cors policy problem but I resolved it using [ng2-pdf-viewer Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43068590/ng2-pdf-viewer-access-control-allow-origin) advice. ---> DomSanitizer solution.

```
this.pdfSrc = this.sanitizer
        .bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.translateService.instant('someLabel'));
```

Now it says to me : "ERROR Error: Invalid parameter object: need either .data, .range or .url". 
The problem is that the src property of the directive is only accepting .data, .range or .url and I give it SafeUrl as the bypassSecurityTrustUrl() return type.

That's how it looks in html :

```
<pdf-viewer class="view-pdf" src="pdfSrc"
                    [render-text]="true"
                    [zoom]="zoom">
 </pdf-viewer>
```

How can I convert safeUrl in a data type which pdf-viewer accepts ?

Comment: did you have a solution for this?

Comment: yup, same .. did you find a fix for the same ?